# Treeview - Adding images files

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, treeview, jpeg

I have code and i need add to treeview only (image files) or image files higlights by other color. Do you have any ideas ? I will like for every advice. I am adding for example Download Folder, in which i have some jpeg, some avi etc. I need images with other color or add just jpeg,png and other image files.

```
   System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
    Image img = new Image();
    public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

     }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dlg.Description = "Vyberte složku, kterou přidat";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtbox1.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
            ListDirectory(treeView1, dlg.SelectedPath);
        }

    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem SelectedTreeViewItem = treeView1.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        string FileName = "";

        if (SelectedTreeViewItem != null)
        {
            FileName = SelectedTreeViewItem.Header.ToString(); 
        }


        {
            canvas1.Children.Remove(img);

            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.SelectedPath + "\\" + FileName));
            img.Width = 250;
            img.Height = 185;
            canvas1.Children.Add(img);


        }



    }

     private void btn4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

         canvas1.Children.Remove(img);
     }

     private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView.Items.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
    }

    private static TreeViewItem CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = directoryInfo.Name };
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));



        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = file.Name});

        return directoryNode;

    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to filter appropriate files:

```
private static TreeViewItem CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = directoryInfo.Name };
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        directoryNode.Items.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(x=> x.Extension == ".jpg" || x.Extension == ".png"))
        directoryNode.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem { Header = file.Name });

    return directoryNode;

}
```

Following code is responsible for selection only pictures:

```
directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(x=> x.Extension == ".jpg" || x.Extension == ".png")
```